# Rails turbolinks - window.load not document.load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I have such code in one .js file:

```
var ready;
ready = function() {
var galleries = $('.car-gallery').adGallery({
    loader_image: '../assets/loader.gif',
    slideshow: {
    enable: false,
    autostart: false,
    speed: 5000,
    start_label: 'Start',
    stop_label: 'Stop',
    // Should the slideshow stop if the user scrolls the thumb list?
    stop_on_scroll: true, 
    // Wrap around the countdown
    countdown_prefix: '(', 
    countdown_sufix: ')',
    onStart: function() {
      // Do something wild when the slideshow starts
    },
    onStop: function() {
      // Do something wild when the slideshow stops
    }
  }});
};
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

but in my rails 4 app i use turbolinks, and sometimes is so,that images are not loaded, but document is ready and i can't start `('.car-gallery').adGallery`

maybe there are any ways to don't reload page, and use window.load with turbolinks? and how?

Comment: Have you tried adding an `alert` to see if that fires?

Comment: @RichPeck it fires when i press ctrl+f5, when go via turbolinks - no

Comment: Is this behavior the same for your `adGallery` plugin too?

Comment: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#jqueryturbolinks check out this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from [JQueryTurbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#jqueryturbolinks), as shown in the comments, it seems your JQuery is not binding to the page load events as it should

I would recommend this code (if you want to keep a native solution):

```
var galleries = function() {
  $('.car-gallery').adGallery({
    loader_image: '../assets/loader.gif',
    slideshow: {
    enable: false,
    autostart: false,
    speed: 5000,
    start_label: 'Start',
    stop_label: 'Stop',
    // Should the slideshow stop if the user scrolls the thumb list?
    stop_on_scroll: true, 
    // Wrap around the countdown
    countdown_prefix: '(', 
    countdown_sufix: ')',
    onStart: function() {
      // Do something wild when the slideshow starts
    },
    onStop: function() {
      // Do something wild when the slideshow stops
    }
  });
};
$(document).on('page:load ready', galleries);
```

Can you try adding this:

```
var alert = function(){
    alert("loaded");
};
$(document).on("page:load ready", alert);
```

---

**Update**

After a conversation, we found this was the solution which worked best:

```
#JS
$('.car-gallery').adGallery({
    loader_image: '../assets/loader.gif',
    slideshow: {
    enable: false,
    autostart: false,
    speed: 5000,
    start_label: 'Start',
    stop_label: 'Stop',
    // Should the slideshow stop if the user scrolls the thumb list?
    stop_on_scroll: true, 
    // Wrap around the countdown
    countdown_prefix: '(', 
    countdown_sufix: ')',
    onStart: function() {
      // Do something wild when the slideshow starts
    },
    onStop: function() {
      // Do something wild when the slideshow stops
    }
  });

#view
<%= link_to "link", path, data: { no-turbolink: true } %>
```

Comment: a little edit... `onStop: function() {
      // Do something wild when the slideshow stops
    }
  });
};`  - ) - is wrong...   also still didn't fire (

Comment: So the `.adGallery` function fires now or not?

Comment: "So the .adGallery function fires now or not? " - "also still didn't fire "

Comment: Wow okay, let's try something else - I'll update with simple alert

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Comment: Does it say which line? All my code looks okay to me

Comment: also 
"if you want to keep a native solution"  - this is not so in need, maybe other solution?

Comment: What I meant there was that if you didn't want to install another gem / JS plugin. I.E if you wanted to just use standard JS & JQuery with Turbolinks